# Problem opening/downloading zip-file after decompression (Java/ZipInputStream)

Tags: java, inputstream, zipinputstream

**The background**
Currently, I try to get a zip-file through a HTTP-servlet with a HTTP-request. The received zip-file contains three different files. These files contain information I want to filter out and doing this from the source is not an option (that's just how it is, though I am aware it would be much better).

Because I cant filter out some information in the file from the source, where the file is build from the beginning, my solution is to decompress the file, read these three files as strings and then filter them. In the end "rebuild" all as a "zipfile" (inputStream) and return the inputStream.

**The problem**
Currently, I've made a class to handle the decompression and filtering of the file. In the end I just want to return the new inputStream containing the zip-file and the three files inside.

I've come as far as get the content from the HTTP entity into a inputStream, decompress this inputStream and get the three files as three strings. To just try to see if this work, I currently don't want to do more than just decompress them and just close the inputStream and return it.. This does however cause an exception when I return the inputStream:

```
 java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
```

This is because the inputStream is used outside the function I present below. As I close the zipInputStream, I probably also closes the inputStream for further work.

**The current code**

```
public InputStream convertInputStream(HttpEntity entity)
{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch (IOException e11)
    {

    }

    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
    Vector <String>entryVector = new Vector<String>();
    ZipEntry entry;
    try
    {
        String entryValue;
        while((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {           
            System.out.println("Unzipping file: " + entry.getName() + "...");
            byte [] buf = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
            zipInputStream.read(buf);
            entryValue = new String(buf);
            entryVector.add(entryValue);
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("error in getting next entry.");
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            zipInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Unzipping done!");
    }
    return inputStream;
}
```

I hope I manage to express this as clear as possible. I can still see that this is very confusing to understand when I can't show the whole solution outside this function.

Comment: "the same zip-file is trying to be downloaded, the link changes and I cant reach the file." - can you give more detail here?

Comment: Hm. Saying the link changes might not be true, but the browser says the file can not be found, so somehow, the name has been corrupted?

My theory is that while closing zipInputStream, I'm also closing the underlying stream; inputStream (which is used later after the execution of this function).

Comment: How is a browser involved? Your example reads a zip file, prints the name of the files and then closes the zip file. Where does the browser come in?

Comment: Ye, that doesn't really have to do with the error, bad explanation from me. When calling zipInputStream.close() I get the exception I updated above.

*edit* I cleaned up the question. */edit*

Comment: What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: The end purpose (this is just the beginning of class) is to decompress a zip-file, get the content, change some in these file, and then compress again and shuffle it out...

Comment: What else is in the InputStream? Can you give us some more context? What are you trying to do when the exception is raised?

Comment: Tried to explain more further.

Comment: Ok, I understood a lot more. What I still don't understand is what you are trying to read from the InputStream when the exception is thrown.

Comment: The thing is that I use IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream); after the change of the inputStream. I know see I've understood this abit wrong. I want to change the inputStream before that is done, which is quite complicated and as I see it, not as these things are suppose to work. 

Any ideas on an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you print "unzipping file", you are not actually unzipping anything. If you want to do that, you need to read the content of the entry from the ZipInputStream using the read() function and write that to a file.

EDIT:
You can try reading the (compressed) zip file from the input stream into a byte array. Then create a ByteArrayInputStream on that array and then wrap your ZipInputStream around that. Then you can safely close the input stream without closing the underlying stream.

Also, make sure that the file's content as String is actually useful. new String(byte[]) creates a string using the default encoding, so this may very well be useless.

Comment: Hm, of course, I missed that detail :P.
But, this shouldn't corrupt the originating zip-file?

Comment: No, it should not, since the file is not altered.

Comment: Hmm. Okey. 
My problem is that I have an inputstream, where I want to change the content of some files inside the zip-file. After that, I want to compress it again and have it all as an inputstream again, which seems pretty off as you normal uses this kind of technique... I need it as an inputstream because of using the function IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);. So the returned value after changed the content and compressed, should be an inputstream...

Comment: But this input stream has nothing to do with the input stream you are getting. You need to return a new input stream reading from your modified zip file.

Comment: Yes, I've manage to understand that too. The problem I see is to get a new inputstream... I've manage to get an ByteArrayInputStream so far :),

Answer (score 1):

So you're not "downloading" via network? By download you mean to decompress files from a zip-archive to your local hard-disk?

You can easily decompress a zip file with these methods:

```
    private static File unZipFile(File zipFileIn) throws Exception {
        ZipFile unZipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileIn);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = unZipFile.entries();
        String topFile = null;
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                // Assume directories are stored parents first then children
                String extractFile = entry.getName();
                if (topFile == null) {
                    topFile = extractFile;
                }
                // This is not robust, just a quick solution
                (new File(entry.getName())).mkdir();
                continue;
            }
            copyInputStream(unZipFile.getInputStream(entry),new BufferedOutp    utStream(new FileOutputStream(entry.getName())));
        }
        unZipFile.close();
        File newFile = new File(zipFileIn.getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile(),topFile);
        return newFile;
    }

    private static final void copyInputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
            while((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

The method returns you a File, which is the root of the decompressed files.

**Perhaps it would be a good idea to ask your question more detailed on what you are trying to do. ATM everybody is guessing what you are trying to do instead of working on a solution.**

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll update my question in a moment to try to explain the purpose of all this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to read the contents on each entry and then call entry.closeEntry()

Comment: Yes. Code now updated, throws exception if trying to close the zipInputStream. If not, zip-file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to download the zip file whilst saving it simultaneously in binary **and** unzipped form. If that is the case, I would say download it first in binary form, then unzip it separately file disk afterwards.

If you don't want both, then you can choose which one you want to do, either by writing the plain stream to disk to get a binary zip file (no need to use a ZipInputStream); or by using a ZipInputStream and reading the data from each entry and writing it to disk (but don't use the plain input stream for writing to disk).